# Strange JavaScript behaviour, variable changing value before converter function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm passing down some JSON data from Smarty. I'm applying this to a JavaScript variable, `options`.

If you've seen my previous question about date formats you'll know I need to do a bit of work on the data coming in, so I've got a function called `chart_convert_dates()` that's called, passing in the options (well, `options.data`), and upon it's return setting it back again.

If you read through my code you'll notice I'm debugging the options variable, and it changes from the original *before* the function is called!?

If I comment out the function call, the variable is untouched, as it should be at that point.

This happens with Chrome, FF... what's going on?

```
{literal}

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // set JS var, this data is coming in from smarty
            var options = {/literal}{$options}{literal};

            // these should both be exactly the same
            debug.debug({/literal}{$options}{literal});
            debug.debug(options);

            // but the above outputs aren't the same! options has been modified
            // by the function below... that hasn't even fired yet!? We can prove
            // this by commenting out the following function call

            options.data = chart_convert_dates(options.data);

            // ... do something else

        });

    </script>

{/literal}
```

Comment: What is the generated code? Perhaps you can see the caveat there.

Comment: What happens if you use alert instead of debug.debug? Have you set a breakpoint and inspected the value?

Comment: @Johannes I have put a breakpoint in, and the variable isn't being changed before the function... must be an issue with the `debug.debug` as Matt pointed out. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, of course, impossible.

You'll probably find that the `debug.debug()` function is saving a reference to the object it is provided with, rather than converting it to a string immediately. When you then view the contents of it's argument *at a later time*, the output will reflect the current state of the object, rather than the state it *was* in.

This is best explained with the following example:

```
var debug = {
    report: function () {
        // console.log(this._value);
    },
    debug: function (arg) {
        this._value = arg; // save a reference
    }
}

var options = {
    foo: 1
};

debug.debug(options);

options.foo = 2;

debug.report(); // will show 2 (http://jsfiddle.net/zQFPm/)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQFPm/

Comment: Many thanks Matt, well explained, pretty sure that's what's going on.